# Tracking events using Google Tag Manager

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I've been attempting to pick up a bit of Javascript for analytics since starting to use Google Tag Manager.
Currently, I'd like to track exit links and am using the following custom html snippet:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

$(document).ready(function(){ 

    $('.app-cta a').onClick=_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'App', 'Click', 'iOS']);

});
</script>
```

The firing rules are:

```
{{event}} equals GAevent
```

I then tried a firing rule:

```
{{url}} matches RegEx .*
```

No luck. Nothing being picked up in Google Analytics nor in HTTPfox.

I'm still getting my head around Google Tag Manager.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use dataLayer.push, not _gaq.push, and your onClick function is incorrect. Should look something like this:

```
<script>
    $('.app-cta a').click(function(event){
        dataLayer.push({
            'event':'GAevent',
            'eventCategory': 'App', //create a datalayer variable macro called eventCategory
            'eventAction': 'Click', //create a datalayer variable macro called eventAction
            'eventLabel': 'iOS' //create a datalayer variable macro called eventLabel
        });
    });
</script>
```

This Custom HTML tag should fire {{url}} matches RegEx .*

In addition to this setup, you'll need to create a new Google Analytics tag with track type = Event. Add your macros (eventCategory, etc) that you created into the Event Tracking Parameters, and set the firing rule to {{event}} equals GAevent.

Comment: You mention creating a new GA GTM tag of Event type; is the tag to actually have the name 'GAevent' (in this case), or is the above declaration **'event':'GAevent'** just for matching the rule, i.e. 'GAEvent' occurs nowhere else except in this code? Thanks :)

Comment: The latter, just for matching the rule.