# Google tag manager: tag is fired in real time, but no data in event category google analtyics

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

Please have a look at the images below:

**Google tag setup**
[image: google_tag_top]
[image: google_tag_action]

**Fire rule**
[image: google_tag_rule]

I have used it in a simple web page and a simple tag manager account. The tag is fired in real time and the 'event category' in Google analytics has recorded the 'category', 'action' and 'label'

When I did the same thing to a shared account (shared by many schools and faculties), I can see the tag is fired in real time, but no data is recorded in recorded the 'category', 'action' and 'label.

A similar issue I have: [Google analytics: dataLayer.push not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28236289/google-analytics-datalayer-push-not-working)

Comment: Just a note that you won't be able to see the event data right away in your standard reports, as you will need to wait up to 24 hours for the data to be processed. If you can see it in Real Time then it should show up eventually, and you just need to wait.

Answer (score 0):

Check for any kind of filters in your GA view and fore any kind of mistakes in firing rules of your tag.